# Using Regex how to extract a string until a character only if present, else till end

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to extract string using Regex in python, that starts with word 'swap' till first '/' if present, or till end

> For example:
>
> > **str1**: 'abcd/swap 12345 ijkl/mnop/tyuio'
> > **str2:** 'abcd/swap ijkl 1234'
> > **str3:** 'swap ijklm nop'

> Required Output:
>
> > **from str1**: 'swap 12345 ijkl'
> > **from str2**: 'swap ijkl 1234'
> > **from str3**: 'swap ijklm nop'

I am new to regex and tried many combinations but cant get all 3 situations.

Comment: `import re` `re.search(r'(swap[^/]+)', s)`

Comment: `import re re.search(r'(\bswap\b[^/]*)', s)`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, it works like a charm. Grateful for the extra measure. I had given up on my skills in regex and came up with something like:   s[s.find('swap'):].split('/', 1)[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex offered by Chris Charley is perfectly fine for the three examples you specified but I do not believe would correctly handle the following:

1. It would match 'abcd/unswap 12345 ijkl/mnop/tyuio'
2. It would not match 'abcd/swap'

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UEzuo8/1)

So if the above types of strings are a possibility and if the above results are, in fact, not what you actually want, then consider:

```
\bswap\b[^/]*
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oX5Kqv/1)

1. `\bswap\b` - matches 'swap' only on a word boundary.
2. `[^/]*` - matches 0 or more non '/' characters until it finds either a '/' character or the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient ways to do this is

`r"swap.*?(?:/|$)"`

https://regex101.com/r/ght9hu/1

or  `r"swap.*?(?=/|$)"` with no match of the ender.

https://regex101.com/r/VSX1hp/1

Comment: What about, "Hearing a familiar buzzing sound, Lola grabbed her flyswaper in a / flash"? "Flyswapper" has been known to have been used in games of Scrabble.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - It's really a joke on us. Regex has never been able to parse language. It was a poor choice to use the phrase `word boundary` when there is no such thing in regex.